# Checking if a child element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there is a better way of selecting the span tag that I'm dynamically adding?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

If you click the `.toggle` div, it shows a detailed div with the `id` that matches the `href` of the anchor tag in the particular `.toggle` div.

```
$('.toggle').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var elemHref = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  var id = elemHref.replace('#', '');
  $("#"+id).toggle();
});
```

Before you click, when you hover over the `.toggle` div, it shows `expand` in a span tag if the details div is hidden.  When you are not hovering over the appropriate `.toggle` div, it shows nothing if the details div is hidden and close if the details div is visible.

```
$('.toggle').hover(function(e) 
    {
        $(this).find("a:not(:has(span))").append('<span class="expand">expand</span>');
        $('.expand').eq(0).css({"position":"absolute", "bottom":"0", "right":"-5px"});
    }, 
    function() 
    {
        var elem = $(this).find("a");
        var elemHref = elem.attr("href");
        var visibleDetail = $(elemHref).is(":visible");
        if(visibleDetail)
        {
            $('.expand').text('close');
        }
        else
        {
            elem.empty();
        }
    }
);
```

I've thought that using `.children` might help, but is there a better way altogether than with `.find()`/`.children()`?